# Design a Data Model to predict value of sum of Function

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining, classification, linear-regression, supervised-learning

I am working on a data mining projects and I have to design following model.

I have given 4 feature x1, x2, x3 and x4 and four function defined on these

feature such that each function depend upon some subset of available feature.

e.g.

F1(x1, x2) =x1^2+2x2^2

F2(x2, x3) =2x2^2+3x3^3

F3(x3, x4) =3x3^3+4x4^4

This implies F1 is some function which depend on feature x1, x2. F2 is some feature which depend upon x2, x3 and so on

Now I have a training data set is available where value of x1,x2,x3,x4 is known and sum(F1+F2+F3) { I know total sum but not individual sum of function)

Now using these training data I have to make a model which which can predict total sum of all the function correctly i.e. (F1+F2+F3)

I am new to the data mining and Machine learning field .So I apologizes in advance if this question is too trivial or wrong. I have tried to model it many way but I am not getting any clear thought about it. I will appreciate any help regarding this.

Comment: So... you have F1+F2+F3 and you need to predict F1+F2+F3?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is non-linear regression. You have features

x1 x2 x3 x4 S where  (S = sum(F1+F2+F3) )

You would like to predict S using Xn but S function is non-linear.
Since your function S is non linear, you need to use a non-linear regression algorithm for this problem. Normal [nonlinear regression](http://www.stat.colostate.edu/~hari/regression_book/chapter9.pdf) may solve your problem or you may choose other approaches. You may for example try [Tree Regression](http://www.stat.cmu.edu/~cshalizi/350-2006/lecture-10.pdf) or [MARS (Multivariate Adaptive Regression Splines)](http://www.stat.cmu.edu/~cshalizi/350-2006/lecture-10.pdf). They are well known algorithms and you can find commercial and open source versions.